# Gcc compilation error when compiling a *.cc file

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I have written a simple C program using gcc compiler in Ubuntu enviroment. The code is simple. Howver, when i try to compile, it is giving an error which I am not able to fathom.  Here is the code and the error

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  enum mar_status {
    single,married,divorced
  };
  enum mar_status person1,person2;
  person1 = single;
  printf("%d\n",person1);  //line B
}
```

I am getting the following error when I compile

```
gcc enum2.cc
/tmp/cc6stgaW.o:(.eh_frame+0x11): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I remove the printf statement at line B, everything goes fine. Any ideas as to why the compilation is failing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using gcc to compile C++ code? (`.cc` extension)

Either rename the file to `enum2.c` or compile with `g++`.

Answer (score 2):

> Undefined references to internal run-time library functions, such as __gxx_personality_v0, are also a symptom of linking C++ object files with gcc instead of g++.

Changing file extension from .cc or .cpp to .c will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the compiler - when you say:

```
 gcc enum2.cc
```

it thinks you are compiling C++ code, but you are doing it with gcc, which doesn't link the correct C++ libraries. Use:

```
gcc enum2.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Its running fine. Check : http://ideone.com/bhjlf

I guess your command to compile is wrong.